# Graph algorithm for finding the shortest transportation order route

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have a simple web-app that is modeling the transportation company information system. I would like to implement the feature of automatic computation of the shortest route for the given order.

[new order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APyBl.png)

Order is represented by a set of cargos, each of them has departure/arrival points. I store cities and distances between each pair of them in the database. The problem is to find the shortest route which would allow to transport all these cargos. Start and finish cities are not important, the only interesting aspect is the shortest path which will include loading/unloading of every shipping.

Is there any graph algorithm suitable for solving such problems?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want want one route to deliver all items. This is a variation of [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is NP-Hard (there is no known efficient optimal solution for it). What is the scale of the problem? How much items do you expect to have?

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) could be useful.

Comment: @amit yes, I want all the items to be delivered during a single transportation. As it is a training project, the number of items will be 3-4,   I think. So, it looks like that I would better implement the manual route composing?)

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items is relatively small (like your comment suggests), you can reduce the problem to [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

First, if you don't have the shortest distance between each pair of cities - you can find it using [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). If you already have distance between each pair of cities, you can skip this step.

Now, you have yourself a proper TSP problem, that can be solved easily for low number of cities using brute force, or more complex dynamic programming solutions.

If I were you, I'd start with the naive solution, and if it's not enough - implement more complicated one.

If later on number of cities expend to large sizes, you will need more sophisticated TSP algorithms, and might even have to sattle for non optimal solution due to the nature of the problem. That said, while you are in the realm of only few cities - the existing solutions should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've found the exact definition of the problem - it is Vehicle Routing Problem with Pickup and Delivery (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem). Though this feature is not critical for my app, it's just interesting for me to try to implement it, hope there are some Java libraries able to perform this task.